# Architecture suggestions for ingesting disparate Data Feeds?

Tags: xml, xslt, architecture

Problem description:
I have to ingest data feeds from multiple sources and do an ETL  on them and house them in an Oracle Data Warehouse. The files themselves are .csv files. The files have different formats, attributes, and values.

Let's say for the sake of argument that I have 3 different types of files:

- File1 - I get a new file of this type every day.
  user_id,first_name,last_name
- File2 - I get a new file of this type every week: order_id,
  order_date, order_amount
- File3 - I get a new file of this type every month: part_id,
  part_name, part_description

What's the simplest way to ingest this data and feed it to the ETL step? How can I code, implement a solution that I can use for all types of files, even a currently unknown type File4?

I was thinking of XSLT and XPath as a possible solution here. Convert the .csv files to XML and then write an XSLT template for each File type. Am I on the right track here? What other technologies/tools can help me?

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I used to build ETL jobs with Talend Studio for Data Integration:
https://www.talend.com/products/data-integration

It's one of the most important open source tool for ETL, the learning curve is very fast, and it look perfect for the job you've described: you can read the csv, do all your transformations and then load the results directly on Oracle DB the results. 
It is based on Java, but you won't write a code line (just some basics). Once your jobs are done you can export them as scripts (.sh or .bat) and schedule them.